# VBA: Returning A Worksheets Object Reference From A Function

Tags: function, vba, reference, module

How do I return a Worksheets Object Reference? I've been perusing through various Google searches with nada results.

For example, I have a functioning code like so. wSheet already dim'ed:

```
Public wSheet As Worksheet
...
Set wSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleSheet")
wSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
```

However, I want wSheet to now call a module that supplies it to the correct reference. Something like this:

```
Public wSheet As Worksheet
...
Set wSheet = myModule.get_ExampleSheet
wSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
```

And then have a function in module myModule

```
Function get_ExampleSheet() As Worksheets
    get_ExampleSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleSheet")
End Function
```

Everything I try gives me various runtime errors. Is there anyway to get this to work?

Thanks and advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are returning the wrong type of object in your function.

```
Function get_ExampleSheet() As Worksheets
    get_ExampleSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleSheet")
End Function
```

This currently has several errors.

```
Function get_ExampleSheet() As Worksheet
   Set get_ExampleSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Function
```

Note I changed:

1. Return type to `Worksheet` (you are trying to set a variable, wSheet, which is of type `Worksheet` to a `Worksheets` type variable)
2. Added `set` keyword
3. Changed to `.Worksheets` to `.Sheets` to return the specific sheet you are interested in

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Lookup()
Dim state As Variant
Dim PodName As Variant
Set state = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
PodName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(state, Range("A1:C55"), 2, False)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F") = PodName
End Sub
```

Macro should stop once the target cell is blank

Answer (score 1):

In order to return an Object from a function, you need to provide the `Set` keyword:

```
Function get_ExampleSheet() As Worksheet
    Set get_ExampleSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleSheet")
End Function
```

Comment: The problem was that the function (in your question and in my answer before I edited it) had `WorksheetS` as return type - which is a collection of `Worksheet` objects! Thus, remove the `s`, so that a `Worksheet` is returned (and still use the `Set` keyword)!

Answer (score 1):

http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/index.php/the-complete-guide-to-worksheets-in-excel-vba/

in your regular part of the code

```
    Dim issues_sheet As Worksheet
    Set issues_sheet = create_working_sheet("Issues")
    issues_sheet.Range("A1").Value = "bssssbb"
```

the function can be something like

```
Function create_working_sheet(sheet_name As String) As Worksheet


For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = sheet_name Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next i

If Not exists Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = sheet_name
    'if we want it at the end
    'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sheet_name
End If
Set create_working_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name)
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

A complete overview of the ways you can set a worksheet using VBA can be found here: http://codevba.com/excel/set_worksheet.htm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.